# Configure SNMP Trap reciever

Tags: snmp

I am doing some work related to my thesis , and I'm using Ubuntu 12.04. I need to receive SNMP traps on this machine , however I'm finding problems in configuring the `snmpd deamon`. Can someone guide me how I can do this please ?

I'm quite a newbie in using Linux so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi belacqua , i apologise for the late update. Managed to solve this using config guide which comes with snmp. Thanks anyways :)

Comment: You can also try summarizing your answer here (i.e., answer your own question) to help others in the future.